# what are the differences between these returning-address of local functions?

Tags: c++, reference

I have the following functions (wrote in Visual C++ 2005)

```
int &getInt_1()
{
    int a = 5;
    int &p = a;
    int p1 = p; // Line 1
    return p1;
}

int &getInt_2()
{
    int a = 5;
    int &p = a;
    return p;
}
```

As I have known so far, both the above functions return address of local variable. If I am right, then I have some questions as follows:

1. What are the differences between above functions? Why `getInt_1()` gets warning from the compiler (`"returning address of local variable"`) while `getInt_2()` does not?
2. What does `Line 1` mean? After `Line 1`, does `p1`  become a reference to `a` as well?

Comment: Undefined behavior ... unnoticed by compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `getInt_1` returns a reference to p1. `getInt_2` returns a reference to a. Both are the same undefined behavior, don't do it. VC should give a warning on both.
2. No, you just copy the value.

Answer (score 1):

1) Both are undefined behavior, because of what you pointed out. It's probably an oversight in MSVS.

2) No, `p1` does not become a reference itself. That line is equivalent to `int p1 = a;`

Comment: @Pubby are you sure? I remember the standard saying just returning a reference to a temporary is UB.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, it's easy for the compiler to show that you're returning a reference to a local variable; in the second case it's harder, because it just has an arbitrary reference that happens to refer to a local variable. That's probably why you get the warning in the first case but not the second.

And no, in the first case `p1` is just a normal `int`, not an `int&`.